# Creating GUI apps in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on a GUI app to be used in Google Sheets. I have a configuration file which contains my config data stored in an array of object, within this array of an object there are properties of which its values I want to be configured on the GUI form.

```
function getGmail2GDriveConfig() {
    return {
    // Gmail label for processed threads (will be created, if not existing):
        "processedLabel": "✉ ➔ ▲", 

    // Sleep time in milli seconds between processed messages:
        "sleepTime": 100,

    // Maximum script runtime in seconds (google scripts will be killed after 5 minutes):
        "maxRuntime": 280,
    // Timezone for date/time operations:
        "timezone": "GMT",
    // Processing rules:
        "rules": [
  { // Replace all files with the variable 'filenameTo' string.
      "filter": "from:example@domain.com", // Email to extract attachments from 
      "folder": "Examples2/exampleA/exampleB/exampleC", // Folder to send attachments to in Gdrive
      "filenameTo": "'%s' ~ yyyy MM dd", // format of renaming files if {RenameFile is set to true}
      "Renamefile": true, // Turn renaming of files on and off
      "globalFilter": "has:attachment in:test1-test2 -in:trash -in:drafts -in:spam", // Labels to fetch attachments from in Gmail
      "markUsRead": true,
      "newerThan": "1m", // how far back to fetch attachments
      "archive": true // Turn achiving on and off     
  }
]
};
}
```

These properties are ones I want to be configured in the form fields: filter,folder,Renamefile,globalFilter,markUsRead,newerThan.
Now, my concern is if I add multiple values in the form fields, won't this override the values stored in the properties, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are these setting specific to a particular service?  Or are these your own custom settings?  From your explanation I don't know what the larger context of your situation is and I'm not familiar with those settings.  If these are Apps Script settings, do you have a link to the documentation.

Comment: Is your UI built in HTML? If you'd like your form to contain data that can't be changed, you can use <input type="hidden" name="property" value="value">

Comment: @SandyGood, these are my custom settings.

Comment: I have form fields which contain the following entries: filter--the email address field,folder---text field,Renamefile--boolean,globalFilter---gmail search expressions--text field,markUsRead--boolean,newerThan--text field.
and i have a add and remove button, so everytime the add button is clicked it should store the data from the form fields into these property values of the above code